# Open Layers 3 center the map based on extent on vector layer?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers-3

I want to position the center and zoom level of my map depending on the vector layer features (points).

I have a geojson file which is populating my map:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   url: 'assets/js/data.geojson',
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   projection: 'ESPG:3857'
});
```

I now try to get the extent of the vector layer:

```
vectorSource.once('change', function (e) {
    if (vectorSource.getState() === 'ready') {
        if (vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length > 0) {
            map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
        }
    }
});
```

How can I get the coordinates of the map based on the layer features and zoom to specific level?

```
map.setCenter("// Center position of lon,lat based on layer features//");
map.setZoom("// Zoom level according to layer features//");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use `map.getView().fit(...)` you're already `centering` and `zooming`. Do you want to know the center and zoom after this?

```
vectorSource.once('change', function(evt){
  if (vectorSource.getState() === 'ready') {
    // now the source is fully loaded
    if (vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length > 0) {
      map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());

      console.info(map.getView().getCenter());
      console.info(map.getView().getZoom());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I did not realised that! thought I still had to apply a setCenter to it.
This is now resolved! Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the [fit](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit) method, there are some options. You're welcome.