# How to fit the view to all features in a source of vector tiles?

Tags: openlayers

Using openlayers version 4, how do I fit the view to all features in a source of vector tiles?

After I identified the source is ready by listenting to the `tileloadend` event. I can't use `map.getView().fit(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());` because `getExtent` is not a function. But I found [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041570/open-layers-3-center-the-map-based-on-extent-on-vector-layer) where people are able to get the extent of sources. Is this a limitation of vector tiles sources? If so, is there a way to work around this limitation, maybe listing all the features of the source?

Here is the code I have so far: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wokiqoxajo/1/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

[`getExtent`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.VectorTile.html#getExtent) method is for layers not the source. And there is no `getFeatures` method available for vector tiles.

```
vectorLayer.getSource().once('tileloadend', function (evt) {
    if (vectorLayer.getSource().getState() === 'ready') {
        map.getView().fit(vectorLayer.getExtent(), map.getSize());
        console.info(map.getView().getCenter());
        console.info(map.getView().getZoom());
    }
})
```

I've modified your code and checked, the layer still returns `undefined` extent.

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
var extent = vectorTile.getExtent()
```

and after use it to fit

```
map.getView().fit(extent, { options });
```